# Drupal - how to include "|" as a dividor for each menu item

Tags: drupal, menu, divider

I am using Drupal 7 with Zen theme.  I want to add a menu in the navigation bar with the following requirements:
1. background:grey
2. a divider "|" dividing each menu item
3. no underline for the menu item

I was able to accomplish #1 in the navigation.css file.  Can you tell me how to accomplish 2 and 3?
--------------------------------------the answer -----------------------------------

for those who are interested, here's how I accomplish the above:

1. setting background to grey, edit responsive-sidebars.css, add "background:grey" under #navigation code-block.
2. adding a divider "|": edit navigation.css, add the following code:

   ```
   #navigation li:before {
       content: "|";
    }
   ```
3. no underline for the menu item, edit navigation.css, add "text-decoration:none" and #navigation a to "#navigation ul.links li" code pile like this:

   ```
   #navigation ul.links li,
   #navigation ul.menu li,
   #navigation a
   { 

     padding: 0px 5px;
     margin-right: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
     float:left;
     color:white;
     vertical-align: middle;
     list-style: none;
     text-decoration: none;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

How about just putting a style on the element you are working with (FOO) that does something like:

```
FOO:before {
    content: "|";
}
FOO:first-child:before {
    content: "";
}
```

Where FOO is the class or element that you are working with for your nav.

What's happening here is you're using a pseudo-element to place the pipe before your element, and the first-child is there to make sure you don't have the pipe in front of your first item. 
(The opposite, using :after and :last-child would be equally effective)